# Rubyにおいて、協定世界時でUNIX時間を表示させるには？

Tags: ruby

UNIX時間　0
協定世界時　1970-01-01T00:00:00
日本標準時　1970-01-01T09:00:00
となることは理解しているのですが、
文字列strを協定世界時のつもりで、
Time.parse(str).to_i
としても、日本標準時でUNIX時間を表示されてしまいます。
そこで以下のようにしたのですが、
文字列strを協定世界時のままでUNIX時間を表示できないのでしょうか？

```
require 'time'

# JST
['1970-01-01 09:00:00', '2016-02-29 09:00:00', '2038-01-19 12:14:07'].each{|str| p Time.parse(str).to_i}

# UTC
['1970-01-01 00:00:00', '2016-02-29 00:00:00', '2038-01-19 03:14:07'].each{|str| p Time.parse(str).to_i + 32400}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'UTC'をつけてパースするのはいかがですか？

```
require 'time'
['1970-01-01 00:00:00', '2016-02-29 00:00:00', '2038-01-19 03:14:07'].each{|str| p Time.parse(str + ' UTC').to_i}
```

結果

```
0
1456704000
2147483647
```

Comment: ちゃんと、UTCとして文字列を読み込めばよいということですか！ありがとうございます。